# Why does the ng-repeat derective not work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning the basics of angular and I cannot understant, why ng-repeat does not work.

File app.js

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store', [ ]);

app.controller('StoreController', function(){
this.product=gems;

});

var gems = [
    {
        name: "Dodecahedron",
        price: 2.95,
        description: '...',
        canPurchase: true,
    },  
    {
        name: "Pentagonal Gem",
        price: 5.95,
        description: '...',
        canPurchase: false,
    }
];
})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app="store">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
        <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
            <h1>{{store.product.name}}</h1>
            <h2> ${{store.product.price}}</h2>
            <p>{{store.product.description}}</p>
            <button ng-show="store.product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart </button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Would like to add that if I try to view it not dinamically (like store.product[0].description) it works regularly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function(){
  var app = angular.module('store', []);


  app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope) {
     $scope.products = [{
          name: "Dodecahedron",
          price: 2.95,
          description: '...',
          canPurchase: true,
       }, {
          name: "Pentagonal Gem",
          price: 5.95,
          description: '...',
          canPurchase: false,
      }];
  });

})();

<body ng-controller="StoreController as store">
    <h1>APP</h1>

    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
        <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
        <h2> ${{product.price}}</h2>
        <p>{{product.description}}</p>

        <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsbin.com/dejita/1/

Answer (score 2):

you are using `products` variable  in html. so replace with this:

```
this.products=gems;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you at first assign this.product=gems; and only then define gems. Also you refer to product as `product` inside `for in` and not as store.product. Working example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="plunker">
        <div data-ng-controller="StoreController as store">
            <div ng-repeat="product in store.products">
                <h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
                <h2> ${{product.price}}</h2>
                <p>{{product.description}}</p>
                <button ng-show="product.canPurchase"> Add to Cart </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
            app.controller('StoreController', ['$scope', function($scope){
                this.products=[
                    {
                        name: "Dodecahedron",
                        price: 2.95,
                        description: '...',
                        canPurchase: true,
                    },  
                    {
                        name: "Pentagonal Gem",
                        price: 5.95,
                        description: '...',
                        canPurchase: false,
                    }
                ];

            }]);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```